# How to check if the object returned is a UIView in Swift

Tags: swift

I am Jasmeen Bong. I want to create a new application with a single button (UIButton) at the top of the screen. I create and add a file called RandomObject.swift to my project. When the button is pressed, my application will call the randomObject class method from the RandomObject class.

Below is the code inside my RandomObject file. In this file, i want to write a function that will return me either a UIView or UILabel randomly.

```
class RandomObject: NSObject {

//create a frame for the object
class func _randomFrame() -> CGRect {
let x: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 220)
let y: CGFloat = CGFloat((arc4random() % 200) + 100)
return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 100)
}

//create an uilabel
class func _createUILabel() -> UILabel {
    let randomFrame: CGRect = RandomObject._randomFrame()
    let label = UILabel(frame: randomFrame)
    label.text = "UILabel"
    return label
}


//create a uiview
class func _createUIView() -> UIView {
    let randomFrame: CGRect = RandomObject._randomFrame()
    let aView = UIView(frame: randomFrame)
    return aView
}



class func randomObject() -> Any {
    // create a random generator that get value between 0 - 7
    arc4random_stir()
    let randomNum: Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)
    // Return value of anonymous type, but conforms to NSObject protocol
    var returnObj: NSObject? = nil

    //use switch case to create returnObj randomly
    switch randomNum {
    case 0:
        returnObj = RandomObject._createUILabel()
    case 1:
        returnObj = RandomObject._createUIView()
    default:
        print("error")
    }

    //return the returnObj
    return returnObj
}

}
```

Here is the coding i write inside my viewController file. In here, i want to call the randomObject function and check if the object returned is a UIView. If it is UIView, then set its background colour to random colour and and add it as subview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func PressMeButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    let aObj = RandomObject.randomObject()
    //check if aObj is a UIView
    if (aObj is UIView) {
        let myView = aObj as? UIView
            let red = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(RAND_MAX)
            let blue = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(RAND_MAX)
            let green = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(RAND_MAX)
            let randomColor: UIColor? = UIColor(red: red, green: blue, blue: green, alpha: 1)

            myView?.backgroundColor = randomColor
            self.view.addSubview(myView!)

        }
}
```

But my problem is my if statement here:

```
if (aObj is UIView)
```

It cannot help me to check the object returned is a UIView and or a UILabel. As a result, UILabel will also be added as subview. May i know how to solve this?
Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Could you do something like `if (aObj is UIView) && !(aObj is UILabel)`?

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem !

Comment: Thanks for telling me. You've made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Since UILabel inherits from UIView, your check `aObj is UIView` will succeed for both. If you want to treat UILabels differently, you need to check for them first:

```
if let lbl = aObj as? UILabel {
   // do label stuff
} else if let view = aObj as? UIView {
   // do view stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me